# Append an SVG Element to HTML Table Cell Using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to append an SVG circle to cells within a table based on the values in those cells using D3.

Here's what I'm trying to get:

```css
        .canvasBackground {
            background-color: white
        }
        
        .table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: #d0d4d5 solid 1px;
            border-spacing: 0px;
            font: normal 11px Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            line-height: 14px;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 100%
        }
        
        .headerStyle {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        
        .headerRowStyle {
            background-color: #fff;
            border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
            color: #4078a9;
            font-size: 14px;
            height: 48px;
            line-height: 14px;
            padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px
        }
        
        .headerCellStyle {
            border-left: 1px solid #d0d4d5;

        }

        .tableBodyStyle {
            text-align: left;
            vertical-align: middle
        }
        
        .tableRowStyle {
            background-color: #fff;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d4d5;
            color: #565656;
            padding: 5px 5px
        }
        
        .tableCellStyle {
            border: 1px solid #d0d4d5;
            
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="canvasBackground">
    <div class="tables">
    <table id="sample" class="table display">
        <thead class="headerStyle">
            <tr class="headerRowStyle">
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Color 1</th>
                <th>Color 2</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="tableBodyStyle">
            <tr class="tableRowStyle">
                <td class="tableCellStyle">Title 1</td>
                <td class="tableCellStyle">00001</td>
                <td class="tableCellStyle">Rena</td>
                <td class="tableCellStyle">
                    <svg width="50" height="50">
                        <g>
                            <circle cx="28" cy="25" r="20" style="fill: rgb(244, 248, 94);"></circle>
                            <text dy="30" dx="24" style="fill: rgb(86, 86, 86);">Y</text>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </td>
                <td class="tableCellStyle">
                    <svg width="50" height="50">
                        <g>
                            <circle cx="28" cy="25" r="20" style="fill: rgb(122, 162, 92);"></circle>
                            <text dy="30" dx="24" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);">G</text>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="tableRowStyle">
                <td class="tableCellStyle">Title 2</td>
                <td class="tableCellStyle">00002</td>
                <td class="tableCellStyle">Elsa</td>
                <td class="tableCellStyle">
                    <svg width="50" height="50">
                        <g>
                            <circle cx="28" cy="25" r="20" style="fill: rgb(122, 162, 92);"></circle>
                            <text dy="30" dx="24" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);">G</text>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </td>
                <td class="tableCellStyle">
                    <svg width="50" height="50">
                        <g>
                            <circle cx="28" cy="25" r="20" style="fill: rgb(216, 75, 42);"></circle>
                            <text dy="30" dx="24" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);">R</text>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's what I have so far:

```js
function evalColor(d) {
    if (d == "Green" | d == "Yellow" | d == "Red") {
        return createSVG(d);
    }
    if (d != "Green" | d != "Yellow" | d != "Red") {
        return d;
    }
}

function evalText(d) {
    if (d == "Green" | d == "Yellow" | d == "Red") {
        console.log(d);
    }
    else if (d != "Green" | d != "Yellow" | d != "Red") {
        return d;
    }
}

function createTable() {
    var dataSet = [{
        "Title": "Title 1",
        "ID": "00001",
        "Name": "Rena",
        "Color 1": "Yellow",
        "Color 2": "Green"
    }, {
        "Title": "Title 2",
        "ID": "00002",
        "Name": "Elsa",
        "Color 1": "Green",
        "Color 2": "Red"
    }, ];

    var div = d3.select('.tables');

    // append a table to the div
    var table = div.append("table")
        .attr({
            id: "sample",
            class: 'table'
        })
        .classed("display", true);

    // append a header to the table
    var thead = table.append("thead")
        .attr({
            class: 'headerStyle'
        });

    // append a body to the table
    var tbody = table.append("tbody")
        .attr({
            class: 'tableBodyStyle'
        });

    // append a row to the header
    var theadRow = thead.append("tr")
        .attr({
            class: 'headerRowStyle'
        });

    // return a selection of cell elements in the header row
    // attribute (join) data to the selection
    // update (enter) the selection with nodes that have data
    // append the cell elements to the header row
    // return the text string for each item in the data array
    theadRow.selectAll("th")
        .data(d3.keys(dataSet[0]))
        .enter()
        .append("th")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        });

    // table body rows
    var tableBodyRows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
        .data(dataSet)
        .enter()
        .append("tr")
        .attr({
            class: 'tableRowStyle'
        });

    //table body row cells
    tableBodyRows.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(d) {
            return d3.values(d);
        })
        .enter()
        .append("td")
        .append(function(d) {
            return createSVG(d);
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return evalText(d);
        });
}

function createSVG(d) {

    function colorPicker(value) {
        if (value == "Green") {
            return "#7aa25c";
        }
        else if (value == "Yellow") {
            return "#f4f85e";
        }
        else if (value == "Red") {
            return "#d84b2a";
        }
    }

    function colorFill(value) {
        if (value == "Green") {
            return "#fff";
        }
        else if (value == "Yellow") {
            return "#565656";
        }
        else if (value == "Red") {
            return "#fff";
        }
    }

    function letterChoice(value) {
        if (value == "Green") {
            return "G";
        }
        else if (value == "Yellow") {
            return "Y";
        }
        else if (value == "Red") {
            return "R";
        }
    }

    var w = 50;
    var h = 50;

    var kpi = document.createElement("div");

    var svg = d3.select(kpi).append("svg")
        .attr({
            width: w,
            height: h
        });


    var elem = svg.selectAll("div")
        .data([d]);

    var elemEnter = elem.enter()
        .append("g");

    elemEnter.append("circle")
        .attr({
            cx: 28,
            cy: 25,
            r: 20
        })
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return colorPicker(d);
        });

    elemEnter.append("text")
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return colorFill(d);
        })
        .attr("dy", 55)
        .attr("dx", 45)
        .text(function(d) {
            return letterChoice(d);
        });

    return kpi;
}

createTable();
```

```css
        .canvasBackground {
            background-color: white
        }
        
        .table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border: #d0d4d5 solid 1px;
            border-spacing: 0px;
            font: normal 11px Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            line-height: 14px;
            padding: 5px;
            width: 100%
        }
        
        .headerStyle {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        
        .headerRowStyle {
            background-color: #fff;
            border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
            color: #4078a9;
            font-size: 14px;
            height: 48px;
            line-height: 14px;
            padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px
        }
        
        .headerCellStyle {
            border-left: 1px solid #d0d4d5;

        }

        .tableBodyStyle {
            text-align: left;
            vertical-align: middle
        }
        
        .tableRowStyle {
            background-color: #fff;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d4d5;
            color: #565656;
            padding: 5px 5px
        }
        
        .tableCellStyle {
            border: 1px solid #d0d4d5;
            
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="canvasBackground">
 <div class="tables"></div>
</body>
```

Essentially, I'd like to use `.append` method to append `<td>` elements with text if the text does not include a color, like 'Red', 'Yellow', or 'Green. If the text does include those colors, I want to use that same `.append` method to append a child svg cirlce element. But when I use the `.text` method, my svg elements go away.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the order of the calls, and throw a filter in there:

```
  //table body row cells
  tableBodyRows.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d) {
      return d3.values(d);
    })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .text(function(d) {
      return evalText(d);
    })
    // only make the SVG for those text  that have a color
    .filter(function(d){
      return (d === "Green" ||
        d === "Yellow" ||
        d === "Red");
    })
    .append(function(d) {
      return createSVG(d);
    });
```

Working code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style>
    .canvasBackground {
      background-color: white
    }
    
    .table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border: #d0d4d5 solid 1px;
      border-spacing: 0px;
      font: normal 11px Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      line-height: 14px;
      padding: 5px;
      width: 100%
    }
    
    .headerStyle {
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .headerRowStyle {
      background-color: #fff;
      border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
      color: #4078a9;
      font-size: 14px;
      height: 48px;
      line-height: 14px;
      padding: 10px 5px 5px 5px
    }
    
    .headerCellStyle {
      border-left: 1px solid #d0d4d5;
    }
    
    .tableBodyStyle {
      text-align: left;
      vertical-align: middle
    }
    
    .tableRowStyle {
      background-color: #fff;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #d0d4d5;
      color: #565656;
      padding: 5px 5px
    }
    
    .tableCellStyle {
      border: 1px solid #d0d4d5;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="canvasBackground">
    <div class="tables"></div>
  </div>

  <script>
    function evalColor(d) {
      if (d == "Green" | d == "Yellow" | d == "Red") {
        return createSVG(d);
      }
      if (d != "Green" | d != "Yellow" | d != "Red") {
        return d;
      }
    }

    function evalText(d) {
      if (d == "Green" | d == "Yellow" | d == "Red") {
        console.log(d);
      } else if (d != "Green" | d != "Yellow" | d != "Red") {
        return d;
      }
    }

    function createTable() {
      var dataSet = [{
        "Title": "Title 1",
        "ID": "00001",
        "Name": "Rena",
        "Color 1": "Yellow",
        "Color 2": "Green"
      }, {
        "Title": "Title 2",
        "ID": "00002",
        "Name": "Elsa",
        "Color 1": "Green",
        "Color 2": "Red"
      }, ];

      var div = d3.select('.tables');

      // append a table to the div
      var table = div.append("table")
        .attr({
          id: "sample",
          class: 'table'
        })
        .classed("display", true);

      // append a header to the table
      var thead = table.append("thead")
        .attr({
          class: 'headerStyle'
        });

      // append a body to the table
      var tbody = table.append("tbody")
        .attr({
          class: 'tableBodyStyle'
        });

      // append a row to the header
      var theadRow = thead.append("tr")
        .attr({
          class: 'headerRowStyle'
        });

      // return a selection of cell elements in the header row
      // attribute (join) data to the selection
      // update (enter) the selection with nodes that have data
      // append the cell elements to the header row
      // return the text string for each item in the data array
      theadRow.selectAll("th")
        .data(d3.keys(dataSet[0]))
        .enter()
        .append("th")
        .text(function(d) {
          return d;
        });

      // table body rows
      var tableBodyRows = tbody.selectAll("tr")
        .data(dataSet)
        .enter()
        .append("tr")
        .attr({
          class: 'tableRowStyle'
        });

      //table body row cells
      tableBodyRows.selectAll("td")
        .data(function(d) {
          return d3.values(d);
        })
        .enter()
        .append("td")
        .text(function(d) {
          return evalText(d);
        })
        .filter(function(d){
          return (d === "Green" ||
            d === "Yellow" ||
            d === "Red");
        })
        .append(function(d) {
          return createSVG(d);
        });
        
    }

    function createSVG(d) {
      
      function colorPicker(value) {
        if (value == "Green") {
          return "#7aa25c";
        } else if (value == "Yellow") {
          return "#f4f85e";
        } else if (value == "Red") {
          return "#d84b2a";
        }
      }

      function colorFill(value) {
        if (value == "Green") {
          return "#fff";
        } else if (value == "Yellow") {
          return "#565656";
        } else if (value == "Red") {
          return "#fff";
        }
      }

      function letterChoice(value) {
        if (value == "Green") {
          return "G";
        } else if (value == "Yellow") {
          return "Y";
        } else if (value == "Red") {
          return "R";
        }
      }

      var w = 50;
      var h = 50;

      var kpi = document.createElement("div");

      var svg = d3.select(kpi).append("svg")
        .attr({
          width: w,
          height: h
        });
        
      var elem = svg.selectAll("div")
        .data([d]);

      var elemEnter = elem.enter()
        .append("g");

      elemEnter.append("circle")
        .attr({
          cx: 28,
          cy: 25,
          r: 20
        })
        .style("fill", colorPicker);

      elemEnter.append("text")
        .style("fill", colorFill)
        .attr("dy", 30)
        .attr("dx", 25)
        .text(letterChoice);

      return kpi;
    }

    createTable();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Super, @Mark. Thanks! I wasn't aware of the .filter method. Also, appreciate you cleaning up the code as well.

Comment: .filter is SUPER useful, and not restricted to d3!